# Run a macro for all sheets to insert a row and copy formula from above cells

Tags: vba, excel

I search a macro that is if inserted a new row, then *Column A* cell of that new row will fill-down above cell formula which deals with auto numbering. The formula is:

> =IF(TRIM(B3)<>"",COUNTA($B$3:B3)&".","")

In *Column B*, I have names of 300 Staff of my organization with one row interval to differentiate between States. If a new staff join our organization, I need to insert a row within his/her State.
And I use a macro below to work it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = ActiveCell.Column Then
        refRow = Target.Row - 1
        thisRow = Target.Row
        Range("A" & refRow & ":A" & refRow).Copy Range("A" & thisRow & ":A" & thisRow)
    End If
End Sub
```

It works fine in **Sheet1**. Here is my problem:

In *Column A and B* of **Sheet2** and **Sheet3**, I link rows with **Sheet 1's** *Column A and B*, by using simple:

> =Sheet1!A3 
> =Sheet1!B3

These two columns of all sheets are the same, starting at row 3 of all sheets.
I want an event that if I insert a new row in **Sheet1**, then it will insert a new row of same position into **Sheet2** and **Sheet3**. Then copy relative formula from the above cells in **Sheet2** and **Sheet3**.
I have got the above macro for **Sheet1**, but can't apply to all Sheets.
I tried to copy that macro into **Sheet2** and **Sheet3**, but it doesn't work.
How could I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick... Obviously I'm assuming your sheet names are Sheet1 and Sheet2 respectively. if not you'll know where to change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = ActiveCell.Column Then
        refRow = Target.Row - 1
        thisRow = Target.Row
        Range("A" & refRow & ":A" & refRow).Copy Range("A" & thisRow & ":A" & thisRow)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & refRow & ":B" & refRow).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & thisRow & ":B" & thisRow)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & refRow & ":B" & refRow).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & thisRow & ":B" & thisRow)
    End If
End Sub
```